# How can cilents get ip addresses during booting time via dhcp server

Tags: boot, dhcp, ip-address

I have installed a dhcp server and it is working fine. When I open the terminal on the clients side, they have got the address. The problem is that when I booted the client machines they didn't get the dynamic address and I
don't know why.

Help me and let me know how I can solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your dhcp.conf you will see a stanza with the hostname and mac address, this will setup the IP.  You can google 'dhcp.conf examples' to see how its setup.  Hope this helps.

[mattcurry.com](http://www.mattcurry.com)

Comment: yeah it works thnkew

Comment: Please upvote if it helped you. :-)